# how to compile multiple scss files into multiple css files with grunt-sass?

Tags: sass, gruntjs

i would like to compile all SCSS files that are inside scss folder and are not imported ( file names do not start with _ ) each into separate CSS files( that has the same name as SCSS file ).

that kind of functionality that can be found in Prepros.

is it possible to do it with grunt-sass?

i tried this but it doesn't work:

```
sass: {
  dist: {
    files {
      'css/*.css': 'scss/*.scss',
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
sass: {
    dist: {
      files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'styles',
        src: ['*.scss'],
        dest: '../public',
        ext: '.css'
      }]
    }
}
```

Comment: B.r.i.l.l.i.a.n.t!

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your file object dynamically, see here:
http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically